# Is SGST applicable if UGST is applied on purchase or sales?

Tags: india, gst

If my transaction belongs to union territory.
Is SGST also applicable when UGST is applied for such transaction?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about company taxation and not personal finance

Comment: No it is not about company taxation just transaction between retailer and customer. When retailer has bought goods from other state.